# Is there notation or a name for the complement of the unbounded face of a planar graph?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation

Let $G$ be a finite graph embedded in $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $F$ denote denote its unbounded face.  Is there notation or a name for $F^c$ without referring directly to $F$.  Of course this is equivalent to the union of $G$ with all its bounded faces.

More generally, if $G$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{C}$, and $F$ is the unbounded component of $G^c$, I would like notation for $F^c$ which refers to $G$ and not $F$.

If there is no notation already I will probably use "$\text{fill}(G)$", because I am "filling" $G$.  Any better suggestion?

Comment: The *interior* of G?

Comment: @Theophile The interior of $G$ already has a well defined meaning, which is quite different from the meaning I am trying to get at.

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing this a while ago: "given set $A$, let $B$ be the complement of $\infty$ in $\mathbb C\setminus A$". I did not find any notation or term for this thing,

But I know that the term [filled-in Julia set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filled_Julia_set) is in wide use, and it means precisely the operation you describe, applied to the Julia set of something. So, to generalize this to an arbitrary set $G$ and call the result $\operatorname{fill}(G)$ makes perfect sense.